# Extract a row from table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to extract a specific row of data from a table in a live webpage using the following code.

```
requestCrossDomain('https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/sse/grid.cgi?&num=197110&lat=23&submit=Submit&hgt=100&veg=17&sitelev=&email=skip@larc.nasa.gov&p=grid_id&p=T10M&p=DLYRANGE&step=2&lon=16', function(results) {
    $('#loadedContent').css("display","").html(results);    

    //alert($($('#loadedContent table')[4]).text());
//The above line parses the table i need and displays the content in an alert box.

//But when I try the same line of code to display a specific row, it doesnt display anything

    alert($($('#loadedContent table tr:eq(2)')[4]).text());


 });
```

Note that the Website does not assign a name or id to the tables in its page. so I try to extract the table using the position. I am quite successful until this. But when i try to extract a specific row of data from the table. I could not. What should I do to extract a row of data from the table.

P.S: there are multiple tables in the page and none of it is assigned a name or id

Comment: `alert($('#loadedContent table:eq(4) tr:eq(2)').text());`

Comment: wow. dat was great. thank u :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** selector here

```
alert($('#loadedContent table:eq(4) tr:eq(2)').text());
```

This will select 3rd `tr` inside 5th `table`